# ember twitter bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

page contains table with entities and when user clicks modal window appears with own model

**refusals.hbs**:

```
{{#each model}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{#link-to 'refusal' this}}{{id}}{{/link-to}}</button></td>
        <td>{{username}}</td>
        <td>{{fullname}}</td>
        <td>{{regnumber}}</td>
        <td>{{type}}</td>
        <td>{{amount}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
    {{outlet}}
```

**refusal.hbs**:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="refusalModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog"> {{username}}
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Searching for examples lead me to ember view, so my questions is: is there a true standard way  to operate with modals? My example works fine except i don't know where to call **$('#refusalModal').modal('show')**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots have been discussed on this.

There was a [post](http://hawkins.io/2013/06/ember-and-bootstrap-modals/) by **Adam Hawkins**.

And some pullrequests regarding this,
[PR1](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2926),
[PR2](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3281)

There is a [discuss thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/modal-views-can-we-agree-on-a-best-practice/707/24) too on this.

Inspired by all these,

Here is the latest [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oPIMALo/4/edit) for **Ember-Bootstrap Modals**