# Ember View not finding the controller/action

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to call my controller's action from my view with Ember, but it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of null
```

I just can't find the right way to work with views in ember.

My view layout has a call like:

```
<button type="button" {{action modalConfirmation target="view"}} class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

And my View class tries to call the controller in this fashion:

```
this.get('controller').modalConfirmation();
```

My Controller has something like this:

```
ProjEmber.BananasIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    showModal: function() {
        modalinaView.title = "My Title";
        modalinaView.templateName = "any_template_you_wish";
        modalinaView.append();   
    },
    modalConfirmation: function() {
      console.debug('Action modalConfirmation');
    }
  }
});
```

OBS: it works if I append my view using the helper like this:

```
{{#view ProjEmber.ModalinaView title='A title'}}
    A not so good application of a modal view. Just for the sake of illustration.
{{/view}}
```

You can see the full source on Github, especifically this part of the commit:
https://github.com/lucaspottersky/ember-lab/commit/4862426b39adc0bbcce0b4cc3fd0099439f8dd55#commitcomment-4421854

Comment: When you append is it creating it correctly beside the actions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good likelihood it's failing to be appended within the body, or the scope of your ember app which would be why the events aren't propagating to your actions hash.

You might try appendTo('body')

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access view like this

> var modalinaView = this.container.lookup('view:modalina');

This [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2959) can give you more insights.

You are doing the same as Stefanpenner has done in this [commit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember.js/commit/ca72e5abd032fd7ba8a491618bf81ab1fdd29302#diff-14507db3dc0044b9c698c1e09ce44fd4R565).

And [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2959#issuecomment-20497404) is Wycats reply.

Alternatively, This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653061/ember-twitter-bootstrap-modal-dialog/18654751#18654751) may help you in instantiating modals